# How import/export sqlite database in nativescript/angular android?

Tags: android, sqlite, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to `export` the whole `sqlite database` into sd card `memory` with a `button` `click` for a project (Backup feature). I googled for the same, but seems negative response. I'm using https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite `plugin` for this. Also need to import the `exported database` with file picker. Right now, I'm trying to reach it using java code with `nativescript`. Any `nativescript` way help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution to export database for android was to create a developer page and add a button in it :

**EDITED**

```
<Button class="btn  m-3" height="50" row="1" text="ExportDB" (tap)="exportDb()"></Button>
```

the tap function code is :

```
public exportDb() {
    console.log('######################### exporting DB ##################');
    this.copyAndroidFileUsingStream('/data/data/{your package name }/databases/{database name}.db',
        fs.path.join(this.getDownloadFolderPath(), {output filename}.db));
}

public getDownloadFolderPath() {
    if (!!application.ios) {
        const fileManager = utilModule.ios.getter(NSFileManager, NSFileManager.defaultManager);
        const paths = fileManager.URLsForDirectoryInDomains(15, 1);
        const url = paths.objectAtIndex(0);
        return url.path;
    } else {
        return android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
    }
}

// copy file only for android
    public copyAndroidFileUsingStream = (source, dest): void => {
        let is: java.io.InputStream = null;
        let os: java.io.OutputStream = null;
        try {
            is = new java.io.FileInputStream(source);
            os = new java.io.FileOutputStream(dest);
            //    let buffer = Array.create("byte", 1024);

            const buffer = Array.create('byte', 4096);
            let length: number;
            // tslint:disable-next-line:no-conditional-assignment
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            this.errorService.handleError(e);
        } finally {
            console.log('copy done');
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort, but seems java code in between them, letme try and definitely will mark as correct if its working. Thanks again

Comment: to copy on ios and android you can use this :

`public copyFile(sourceFile: fs.File, destinationFile: fs.File) {
    
            const source = sourceFile.readSync((e) => { console.log(e); });
            destinationFile.writeSync(source, (e) => { console.log(e); });
        }`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, is there any method to import the exported file.?

Comment: you can use http://sqlitebrowser.org/ to open the it in your dev environnement
if you want to import it in your app simply do the reverse copy the database from any source to this folder : "/data/data/{your package name }/databases/ "

Comment: hm, that will replace the existing scehma and data right ?, what if i have a table alteration for a new field.?

Comment: this is the documentation to properly copy a database from another source https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite/blob/master/src/README.md#sqlitecopydatabase