# how to export and import selected tables or complete DB from sqlite database in nativescript in csv or some other format

Tags: javascript, sqlite, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I'm trying to export the whole sqlite database in one case and only selected tables in another case with a button click for a project (Backup feature). I googled for the same, but seems negative response. I'm using https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite plugin for this. Also need to import the exported database with file picker or some other. Right now, I'm trying to reach it using java code with nativescript by referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49146471/8750174. Any nativescript way help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
let is = java.io.InputStream = null;
let os = java.io.OutputStream = null;

try {
    is = new java.io.FileInputStream('/data/data/org.nativescript.Aads/databases/mydatabse.db');
    os = new java.io.FileOutputStream('/storage/emulated/0/aads_Backup/dbincsvformat.csv');

    const buffer = Array.create('byte', 4096);

    while ((is.read(buffer).length) > 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
} catch (e) {
    this.errorService.handleError(e);
} finally {
    console.log('copy done');
    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV is nothing but tab-delimited or comma-separated values in a text file. {N} has its cross platform [file-system module](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/file-system#create), supports read / write on a file.

All you would have to do is pass the comma separate string to the `writeText` / `writeTextSync` method.

Something like,

```
const documents = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.documents();
const file = documents.getFile("test.csv");
file.writeTextSync(`1,2,3\n\r4,5,6`);
```

Comment: this was working perfectly. but how to convert test.db into comma separated value.

Comment: That's a simple job with JavaScript, convert the array of values for each row into string. You may use the `.join(",")` method.

Comment: no i'm not asking this. i have test.db file downloaded from online. now i want to convert this .db file into csv. so as per your guidance i can convert array in csv but how to convert .db into array. sorry if i'm wrong in concept...!  i got stuck here from 2days.

Comment: Use the sqlite plug-in.

Comment: i checked sqlite and i almost played with it. but still i'm not getting what to do. do i need to read table by table and convert each? or is there any easy way. and Sqlite.copyDatabase() this method was confusing there is no documentation and don't know how to use it. can you please give some more details for converting .db file to .csv